# Hide and display elements in the n-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a HTML  like this

```
 div(class="item-detail-attachment-line", ng-repeat="attachment in attachments")
     span {{ attachment.Filename }}
     span
         a(href="", ng-click="deleteAttachment(attachment)") Delete
```

I need to show `Delete` link only when the user mouse-over corresponding `DIV`-element.

What is the best way to do it?

I can use `ng-mouseover` to set array variable in the controller, and `ng-show` to display a link using this vaiable from the controller.

But may be there is a better way without using controller?

Comment: What about using css for this purpose?

Comment: CSS without JS? I am agree, but don't know how. Can you please provide an example.

Comment: correct way is a directive you'll add on your div, to handle the behavior for each element. At least this is the angular way to do it. Quick way for such basic behaviour would be fall back to jquery's "on" or "delegate"

Comment: @PierreGayvallet, do you mean my own custom directive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using css like this.

```
.item-detail-attachment-line a {
  display:none;
}

.item-detail-attachment-line:hover  a {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I chaned `block` to `inline`, but it is I was needed.